# Find the number of positive integers not containing digit $0$ whose digits add up to $10$.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of positive integers not containing digit $0$ whose digits add up to $10$.

Comment: Obviously the maximum number is 1111111111, which has 10 digits, so we are looking for 9-digit numbers at maximum (and we will add 1 to the total).

Comment: Look up _ordered partition_ . This question may help: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31562/number-of-ordered-partitions-of-integer . And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that you have $10$ unities written down in a row:

$$1 \quad 1 \quad 1\quad  1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1 \quad 1$$

You can see that there are 9 empty spaces between them, where you can put a separator. Any arrangement of separators (except for the case when there are no separators) can be mapped to a number with the sum equal to 10: we should merely count the number of unities in each obtained block. For example:

$$1 \quad 1~~~|~~~1\quad  1 \quad 1~~~|~~~1 \quad 1 \quad 1~~~|~~~1 \quad 1$$
This arrangement corresponds to the number $2332$. On the other hand, you can see that for any number there is a unique arrangement of separators representing this number. Thus, it is a bijection.

Since we can select any subset of spaces (except for the empty one) to fill them with separators, the number of ways to make such an arrangement is $2^9 - 1 = 512 - 1 = 511$.

Comment: $(+1)$ from me. This is a very nice bijection! Don't forget to $-1$ for the case where there are no separators between unities.

Comment: @N.Shales good spot, thanks! I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: No problem. The thrust of your work came across loud and clear so that's the main thing :)