# Prove that the general formula for a sequence $a_n$ is $\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, integer-partitions

Here is a sequence $a_n$ where the first five $a_n$ are:

$a_1=-\frac{1}{1!}$

$a_2=-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{1!\times1!}$

$a_3=-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{2}{2!\times1!}-\frac{1}{1!\times1!\times1!}$

$a_4=-\frac{1}{4!}+\frac{2}{3!\times1!}+\frac{1}{2!\times2!}-\frac{3}{2!\times1!\times1!}+\frac{1}{1!\times1!\times1!\times1!}$

$a_5=-\frac{1}{5!}+\frac{2}{4!\times1!}+\frac{2}{3!\times2!}-\frac{3}{3!\times1!\times1!}-\frac{3}{2!\times2!\times1!}+\frac{4}{2!\times1!\times1!\times1!}-\frac{1}{1!\times1!\times1!\times1!\times1!}$

For each term in $a_n$​:

1.The denominator enumerates all combinations that sum to $n$.

2.The numerator represents the number of permutations possible for that combination.

3.If the number of elements in the combination is odd, the term is negative.

I have computed the first five $a_n$ mentioned above, and it appears that $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}$​. However, I am struggling to provide a proof for this formula. Could someone please assist me?

Comment: By 1. I assume you mean [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory))? And 2. is the number of distinct permutations you can form with the terms of each partition?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly integer partitions and distinct permutations.

Comment: Did you invent this problem or is it an exercise?

Comment: I invented it when I try to solve my problem about Taylor expansion. I probably would not ask for help online if it is just an exercise in a math book.

Comment: An obvious remark, though not sure it makes things simpler: you can take the numerator to be $1$ if you consider instead *ordered* integer partitions (for each permutation you get one of them). Then [there are](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31562/number-of-ordered-partitions-of-integer) $2^{n-1}$ ordered partitions of $n$, so $2^{n-1}$ terms in $a_n$.

Comment: Then, multiplying everything by $n!$, you have a sum of multinomial coefficients, that you can split according to partition length, each sub-sum is $u_p=\sum (n; n_1,\dots,n_p)$, with $(n;n_1\dots n_p)=n!/(n_1!\cdots n_p!)$ and the sum runs on all ordered partitions. Checking in [Abramowitz & Stegun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abramowitz_and_Stegun), $u_p=p!S_n^p$ (24.1.2.II.B), where $S_n^p$ are [Stirling number of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), and then $\sum_{p=0}^n (-1)^{n-p}p!S_n^p=1$ (24.1.4.II.B).

Comment: Of course all of this needs a full proof, but at least it's a known relation.

Comment: The second sum is a direct consequence of the relation (which can be a definition) $x^n=\sum_{p=0}^n S_n^p x(x-1)\cdots(x-p+1)$.

Comment: An omission: when I wrote above *"the sum runs on all ordered partitions"*, it's with the additional constraint $n_k\ge 1$ for all $k$. That's implicit as we have split the sum in smaller sums with fixed partition length (all terms of which are $>0$).

Comment: Thank you for your meticulous and insightful answer to this problem. Your clarity in explanation is very helpful.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I recommend you write up an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can prove this combinatorially, using a sign-reversing involution, also known as the the DIE method (Description, Involution, Exception).

First, let us split your sum up in a way such that all numerators are $1$. To do this, we take a sum over all *ordered* partitions of $n$ (also known as compositions of $n$), instead of just the integer partitions of $n$. For example, when $n=4$, this looks like
$$
-\frac1{4!}+\frac1{1!\cdot 3!}+\frac1{3!\cdot 1!}+\frac1{2!\cdot 2!}-\frac1{2!\cdot 1!\cdot1!}-\frac1{1!\cdot2!\cdot1!}-\frac1{1!\cdot1!\cdot2!}+\frac1{1!\cdot1!\cdot1!\cdot1!}
$$
Next, we multiply both sides of the equation to be proved by $n!$. The result is
$$
\sum_{\alpha \text{ is a composition of }n} \binom{n}{\alpha}(-1)^{\text{len}(\alpha)}=(-1)^n\tag1
$$
where...

- $\alpha$ ranges over all lists of positive integers summing to $n$. Each $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k)$ for some $k\in \{1,\dots,n\}$, where $\alpha_1+\dots+\alpha_k=n$.
- $\text{len}(\alpha)=k$.
- $\binom{n}{\alpha}$ is the multinomial coefficient, defined by $$\binom n{\alpha}=\frac{n!}{\alpha_1!\alpha_2!\cdots \alpha_k!}.$$

#### Description

Thinking combinatorially, $\binom{n}{\alpha}$ counts the number of ways to put $n$ distinct items into $k=\text{len}(\alpha)$ distinct boxes, such that box number $i$ receives exactly $\alpha_i$ items for each $i \in \{1,\dots,k\}$. We are counting all such arrangements of $n$ items into some number of boxes, where every box is nonempty, and where arrangements with an even number of boxes count positively, and those with an odd number count negatively.

#### Involution

I will now define a way to divvy up all but one of these arrangements into pairs, where one of the pair counts positively, and the other counts negatively. This means that these pairs cancel themselves out in the count. Here is the method. Assume that the $n$ distinct objects are just the integers from $1$ to $n$. Let $P$ be a particular assignment of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ to some number of distinct boxes (numbered $1$ to $k$), where each box is nonempty. We give describe a different assignment, $P'$, which is the one $P$ will be paired with.

- Say that number $1$ is in box number $i$. If $1$ is all by itself in $P$, then $1$ will be moved to the box on the left, and the box originally containing $1$ is deleted in $P'$ (unless $i=1$, see next bullet). Otherwise, if $i$ is in a box with other numbers, then $i$ gets kicked out to a new box on the right, numbered $i+1$  Example: $$P=\boxed{2,3},\boxed{1\phantom{,}},\boxed{4,5}\quad \iff \quad P'=\boxed{2,3,1},\boxed{4,5}$$
- The only exception to this rule is when $1$ is all by itself, and is in box number $1$. In this case, we instead apply the exact same process to the number $2$. If $2$ is not alone, then kick it out to a new box on the left. If $2$ is alone, and $2$ is NOT in box number $2$, then we re-house $2$ to the box on its left.
- The only exception to this is when $1$ and $2$ are both alone, and in boxes numbered $1$ and $2$ (resp.). In this case, we do the same process with number $3$.
- $\vdots$

It should be clear that this process either adds exactly one box, or deletes exactly one box. Therefore, $P'$ has the opposite parity of $P$, and they cancel each other in the count.

#### Exception

There is exactly one arrangement which does not get a partner from this process. Namely, the arrangement with $n$ boxes, such that box number $i$ contains only the number $i$ for each $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. This is the only arrangement which is not canceled out, and it comes with a sign of $(-1)^n$. Therefore, we conclude that the entire sum in the LHS of $(1)$ is equal to $(-1)^n$, as desired.

Comment: I think I didn't quite understand the answer well. When you say P' has the opposite parity of P and can cancel each other, does that mean a complete cancellation? As your example provided in the first bullet, does it mean $\frac{5!}{2! \cdot1!\cdot 2!}$ cancels $\frac{5!}{2!\cdot 3!}$ ?

Comment: @KniferPlasma No it does not. It is the arrangements themselves which cancel each other, because the arrangements contributing $+1$ and $-1$ to the sum are joined in pairs. There is only one arrangement that has no counterpart.

Comment: @user Thanks, now I got it.